# SELECT JOIN on VARCHAR column not using index on DB2 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-luw

This query is using RELATIONS’s index (on column ACCOUNT_1):

```
SELECT RELATION_ID
  FROM RELATIONS
 WHERE ACCOUNT_1 = 'TEST'

Explain Plan
ID | Operation                   |                     Rows | Cost
 1 | RETURN                      |                          |   39
 2 |  FETCH RELATIONS            |         2 of 2 (100.00%) |   39
 3 |   IXSCAN IX_RELATIONS       | 2 of 243069485 (   .00%) |   30
```

This query should be using RELATIONS’s index (on column ACCOUNT_1), but it is not. It’s doing a tablescan instead:

```
SELECT R.RELATION_ID
  FROM RELATIONS as R
  JOIN ACCOUNTS  as A
    ON A.ACCOUNT = R.ACCOUNT_1

Explain Plan
 ID | Operation                      |                             Rows |     Cost
  1 | RETURN                         |                                  | 16745806
  2 |  MSJOIN                        |                   273182208 of 1 | 16745806
  3 |   TBSCAN                       | 243069488 of 243069488 (100.00%) |  3706243
  4 |    SORT                        | 243069488 of 243069488 (100.00%) |  3706243
  5 |     TBSCAN RELATIONS           |           243069488 of 243069485 |  3253808
  6 |   FILTER                       |         1 of 560701760 (   .00%) | 12961335
  7 |    IXSCAN IX_ACCOUNTS          |           560701760 of 560701737 | 12961335
```

Column ACCOUNT_1 of the RELATIONS table is defined as a VARCHAR(255), NOT NULL

Column ACCOUNT of the ACCOUNTS table is also defined as a VARCHAR(255), NOT NULL

The index on the RELATIONS table is defined as ACCOUNT_1    ASC     VARCHAR(255)

Wondering why the index is not used.

---

**Update**:

I think the reason why the index is not used is because of the volume from ACCOUNTS. Notice the date changes in the following queries.

This query uses the index:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR  
SELECT R.RELATION_ID
  FROM RELATIONS as R
  JOIN ACCOUNTS  as A
    ON A.ACCOUNT = R.ACCOUNT_1
 WHERE A.CREATE_DT >= '2023-09-30 00:00:00.0' 
   AND A.CREATE_DT <  '2023-09-30 05:00:00.0'  <- 5 hours of data, about 232k records
```

This query does not use the index:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR  
SELECT R.RELATION_ID
  FROM RELATIONS as R
  JOIN ACCOUNTS  as A
    ON A.ACCOUNT = R.ACCOUNT_1
 WHERE A.CREATE_DT >= '2023-09-30 00:00:00.0' 
   AND A.CREATE_DT <  '2023-10-04 00:00:00.0'  <- 4 days of data, about 1,9M records
```

Comment: Please, attach here access plans (from the [db2exfmt](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2exfmt-explain-table-format) utility) of these queries.

Comment: There are typical scenarios where a tablescan is faster than an index. It is a matter of percent of data volume touched, what is already in memory, and more. As Mark said, provide more details like the access plan

Comment: I dont have access to db2exfmt tool but I can run/query the explain tables with a view. Added above.

Comment: Thanks @data_henrik , added update. I think volume is the reason why the index is not used